# Colocar Materialize CSS a FileField - Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, materialize

Estoy tratando de usar el [File_CSS](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#file) de Materialize pero no encuentro las forma de hacer que me funcione.

Este es mi model:

```
class ComprobanteDomicilio(models.Model):
    alumno = models.ForeignKey(Alumno, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    url_documento = models.FileField(upload_to=ubicacion_comprobante_domicilio)
```

Este mi formulario

```
class ComprobanteDomicilioForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ComprobanteDomicilio
        fields = ('url_documento',)
```

¿La pregunta es, como le doy el estilo?
Así se ve actualmente:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Aunque es posible agregar atributos a los widgets y campos de un formulario desde la definición del formulario en Django, para agregar elementos `div` no hay forma, así que tienes que hacerlo a mano.

En el caso que comentas, se usan dos controles `input`, pero solo uno de ellos va en tu modelo. Tendrías que modificar tu clase `ComprobanteDomicilioForm` con algo como esto:

```
class ComprobanteDomicilioForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ComprobanteDomicilio
        fields = ('url_documento',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ComprobanteDomicilio, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['url_documento'].widget = TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'file-path validate',
            'placeholder': 'Subur un archivo'})
```

El resto tendrías que hacerlo en la plantilla. Solo debes saber que no puedes usar `{{ form.url_documento }}` porque incluye una etiqueta y no la quieres. Por lo que tendrías que hacer algo así:

```
<form action="#">
  {% for field in form %}

  {% comment %}
    Aqui va el campo alumno
  {% endcomment %}

  <div class="file-field input-field">
    <div class="btn">
      <span>File</span>
      <input type="file">
    </div>
    <div class="file-path-wrapper">
      {{ url_documento.errors }}
      {{ url_documento }}
      {% if url_documento.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ url_documento.help_text|safe }}</p>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Consulta la documentación sobre como recorrer los campos de un formulario: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields